# How does Stack Overflow sanitize the usernames?

Tags: discussion, display-names

The usernames in Stack Overflow are well handled because it's possible to use a wide variety of Unicode characters. It's not so easy because of many tricks like [this one](http://iempty.tooliphone.net/en/create-ios-folder-without-name-no-text/#). Very few websites (I don't know any) authorize so many characters in usernames, so there's maybe something interested to show here.

**How does SO do to allow so many Unicode characters in the username, and at the same time be able to sanitize it and remove some potentially dangerous Unicode characters (such as whitespaces that are not regular whitespaces, etc.)?**

Comment: They have [unicorns](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19479/295232) weeding out the dangerous Unicode characters.

Comment: Hmm... *why* wouldn't it just allow most characters? Where's the danger?  TO͇̹̺ͅƝ̴ȳ̳ TH̘Ë͖́̉ ͠P̯͍̭O̚​N̐Y? Meh. I guess that getting rid of control characters (RTL override etc) should be enough.

Comment: You're asking how you can *not* prohibit the use of certain characters?  The same way you don't prohibit the use of any character; you don't create a rule to prohibit them...

Comment: What happens with    ‍   this? <- Here some characters are removed : http://unicode-table.com/fr/200D/  My question is linked to : which char are allowed / which ones are not allowed?

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski the question is : which are allowed / which are not?

Comment: Sort of related: [Can’t change username to an all-alphabetic word](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231843/can-t-change-username-to-an-all-alphabetic-word)

Comment: related answer of mine  on MSE: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/277871/158100

Comment: @rene Interesting. Are there some usernames featuring this dangerous char : http://unicode-table.com/fr/200D/ ?